# Symfony: How to Import a Sass File into Every Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, symfony, sass

I am currently struggling with this. In my Symfony project I have a `_variables.scss` file, where I keep my global variables (e.g. colors).

This is included in my main scss file like this `@import "variables";` - which works fine. Now I also use VueJs in my project and I would like to use my global variables inside Vue components. Now one way to achieve this is just importing the `variables.scss` itself:

```
//CustomButton.vue
<template>
   ...
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "CustomButton"
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../../scss/_variables.scss";

    //able to use variables here
</style>
```

However with a growing project and different paths, this seems to be unnecessary work. What I'd like to achieve is to load the `variables.scss` into every Vue component **automatically**.

This is quite well explained here: [css-tricks.com - How to Import a Sass File into Every Vue Component in an App][1]

Sadly this does not work in my case (I think the vue.config.js is ignored completly) - the variables are still not usable inside the Vue component. I also tried to add the JavaScript into my  main js file - where I load Vue - however this seems to break stuff (some module exception).

Is there any specific way to achieve this with symfony?

PS: I am using Symfony 5, Sass-Loader 9.0.1, Vue 2.6.12, Vue-Loader 15, Vue-Template-Compiler 2.6.12
[1]: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-import-a-sass-file-into-every-vue-component-in-an-app/

---

**Solution 1:**

````
//webpack.config.js

.enableSassLoader(options => {
    options.additionalData = `
        @import "./assets/scss/_variables.scss"; //path.resolve is not working in my case to import the absolute path
    `
})
```
````

Comment: What are u using to compile ur code? since u are using Symfony I guess u might me using Encore, right?

Comment: @H3lltronik yes, Encore

Comment: @Syllz, it looks like you need to play with this part https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html#having-the-full-control-on-loaders-rules of Encore docs to adapt my example of config to your needs. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with symfony Encore.

Comment: Did you restart the dev server after adding this code? Cos I works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my question:

```
//webpack.config.js

.enableSassLoader(options => {
    options.additionalData = `
        @import "./assets/scss/_variables.scss"; //path.resolve is not working in my case to import the absolute path
    `
})
```

this will import the file in every sass template + vue component

Answer (score 2):

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
                      ? 'vue-style-loader'
                      : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                  'css-loader',
                  {
                      loader:  'sass-loader',
                      options: {
                          data: `
                              @import "functions";
                              @import "variables";
                              @import "mixins";
                          `,
                          includePaths: [
                              path.resolve(__dirname, "../asset/scss/framework")
                          ]                      
                      }
                  }
                ]
            },        
        ]
}
```

this config imports 3 files: "_functions.scss", "_variables.scss", "_mixins.scss" from folder`"../asset/scss/framework"` and no need to use `@import "../../scss/_variables.scss";` every time in your vue components. Maybe, you will adapt this webpack config to your needs or will get some idea to resolve your issue.

Comment: @webprogrammar hi, thanks for your amazing answer. it really helped me a lot and after some research I have now a really simple solution for symfony. I tried your solution too, however the path does resolve wrong in my case. in the end I always have something like `@import c:\...\assets\scss\_variables.scss` instead of `@import c:/.../assets/scss/_variables.scss`. So slash/backslashes are wrong in my case - I don't know why :/ However  I will update my answer with the solution I found. Maybe someone even has a better way. But thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need c:

Since you are using Encore, modify your webpack.config.js, add this code

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore.configureLoaderRule('scss', (loaderRule) => {
    loaderRule.oneOf.forEach((rule) => {
        rule.use.push({
            loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
            options: {
                resources: [
                    // Change this url to your _variables.scss path
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/app/styles/_vars.scss'),
                ]
            },
        })
    })
})
```

You also are going to have to install sass-resources-loader

```
npm install sass-resources-loader
```

Then compile your code again and your sass variables will be available everywhere